# method inside a method call java

Tags: java, methods

How can a method be described in a method call? The prototype of getInstance is getInstance(Properties, Authenticator). Here in place of Authenticator a  method is written. Please suggest some place where i can find solution to such kind of problems.

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is an anonymous implementation of the `Authenticator` abstract class. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an anonymous inner class. The abstract class javax.mail.Authenticator has a method called getPasswordAuthentication. This code overrides that method with the method declared.